# Java Input Validation Design

Tags: java

Novice here, please take it easy on me...

What is the Java/OOP way to cleanup the input validation logic I have below? The check to ensure an `int` has been entered is executed multiple times throughout the `main` method. It feels dirty duplicating input validation lines multiple times. Notice the question changes for each input.

I assume one solution is to pass `keyInput` and the question (a String) to a method that completes the validation and returns `keyInput.nextInt` when the input is good.

What would a non-novice do?

Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner keyInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int level = 0;
        boolean badInput = true;
        int answer = 0;
                
        while (badInput) {
            
            System.out.print("Enter a level between 1 and 4: ");
            
            if (!keyInput.hasNextInt()) {
            
                System.out.println("*** Input is not an integer! ***\n");
                keyInput.next();
                continue;
            
            } 
            
            level = keyInput.nextInt();
    
            if (level < 1 || level > 5) {
                
                System.out.println("*** Number is not between 1 and 4! ***\n");
                continue;
                
            }
            
            badInput = false;
            
        }
                
        MathChallenge game = new MathChallenge(level);

        badInput = true;
        
        while (badInput) {
            
            System.out.print("Enter the sum of " + game.getArray() + ": ");
            if (!keyInput.hasNextInt()) {
            
                System.out.println("*** Input is not an integer! ***\n");
                keyInput.next();
                continue;
            
            }
            ...
```

Comment: `Scanner` has quirks and makes it difficult to write code that works in all cases.  I personally would never use it. Instead I'd read entire lines and then parse out what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a method that contains the repeated code and pass any variable pieces as arguments to that method.

For example:

```java
public int getNumber(Scanner keyInput, String prompt, int min, int max) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
 
        if (!keyInput.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("*** Input is not an integer! ***\n");
            keyInput.next();
            continue;
        } 
            
        number = keyInput.nextInt();
        if (number < min || number > max) {
            System.out.println("*** Number is not between " + min + " and " + max + "! ***\n");
            continue;
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int level = getNumber(keyInput, "Enter a level between 1 and 4:", 1, 4);
    MathChallenge game = new MathChallenge(level);
    int sum = getNumber(keyInput, ""Enter the sum of " + game.getArray() + ": ", 0, 100);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but does getNumber need to be a static method?

Comment: @Kimmel You can make it static, as it doesn't use any class members. You can also leave it non-static. You can also make it private. Up to you. Depends on whether you may later want to override it or make it available elsewhere.

Comment: If I don't make getNumber static I receive compile errors due to it being called from a static context (main).

Comment: Oh, right, I missed that everything was in `main`. If you keep it like that, you either need to make `getNumber` static or first create an object to call it on: `new YourClass().getNumber(...)`